Format error training algorithm for image supervised classification - Google Earth Engine python API in QGIS
I am using Google Earth Engine python API in QGIS to try and run a supervised classification of an aerial image. I started working on a GEE guide on supervised classification, but there seems to be a problem with data format that I can't solve. The error in fact arises even if I use the original code form the GEE guide.
Does someone know if it's fixable?
Error:
ee.ee_exception.EEException: Unrecognized argument type to convert to a FeatureCollection: {'collection': <ee.featurecollection.FeatureCollection object at 0x000001CD080E7820>, 'properties': ['class'], 'scale': 30}

Code used to prepare data:
import ee
import geemap.core as geemap

# Define a function that scales and masks Landsat 8 surface reflectance images.
def prep_sr_l8(image):
  # Develop masks for unwanted pixels (fill, cloud, cloud shadow).
  qa_mask = image.select('QA_PIXEL').bitwiseAnd(0b11111).eq(0)
  saturation_mask = image.select('QA_RADSAT').eq(0)

  # Apply the scaling factors to the appropriate bands.
  def _get_factor_img(factor_names):
    factor_list = image.toDictionary().select(factor_names).values()
    return ee.Image.constant(factor_list)
  scale_img = _get_factor_img([
      'REFLECTANCE_MULT_BAND_.|TEMPERATURE_MULT_BAND_ST_B10'])
  offset_img = _get_factor_img([
      'REFLECTANCE_ADD_BAND_.|TEMPERATURE_ADD_BAND_ST_B10'])
  scaled = image.select('SR_B.|ST_B10').multiply(scale_img).add(offset_img)

  # Replace original bands with scaled bands and apply masks.
  return image.addBands(scaled, None, True).updateMask(
      qa_mask).updateMask(saturation_mask)


# Make a cloud-free Landsat 8 surface reflectance composite.
l8_image = (
    ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2')
    .filterDate('2018-01-01', '2019-01-01')
    .map(prep_sr_l8)
    .median())

# Use these bands for prediction.
bands = ['SR_B2', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B4', 'SR_B5', 'SR_B6', 'SR_B7']

# Manually created polygons.
forest1 = ee.Geometry.Rectangle(-63.0187, -9.3958, -62.9793, -9.3443)
forest2 = ee.Geometry.Rectangle(-62.8145, -9.206, -62.7688, -9.1735)
nonForest1 = ee.Geometry.Rectangle(-62.8161, -9.5001, -62.7921, -9.4486)
nonForest2 = ee.Geometry.Rectangle(-62.6788, -9.044, -62.6459, -8.9986)

# Make a FeatureCollection from the hand-made geometries.
polygons = ee.FeatureCollection([
    ee.Feature(nonForest1, {'class': 0}),
    ee.Feature(nonForest2, {'class': 0}),
    ee.Feature(forest1, {'class': 1}),
    ee.Feature(forest2, {'class': 1}),
])

This is the string triggering the error:
# Get the values for all pixels in each polygon in the training.
training = l8_image.sampleRegions({
    # Get the sample from the polygons FeatureCollection.
    'collection': polygons,
    # Keep this list of properties from the polygons.
    'properties': ['class'],
    # Set the scale to get Landsat pixels in the polygons.
    'scale': 30
})

Here's the link to the GEE guide:
https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/classification#colab-python_1
